# Use SharePoint as front end for access

Tags: 2016, microsoft-access

in SharePoint 2010, you could publish an access database to sharepoint and all the forms and reports would show. I read this is being phased out. In SharePoint 2016 , is it still possible to use SharePoint as a front end for an access db ? I am interesed in the forms, not the tables. I read that SP is pushing people towards using SQL server, but I am just a client side developer, and it is not like I can get my own database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can still use it in SharePoint 2016 Enterprise Edition.

> **Note:** In SharePoint 2019, Access Services 2010 and 2013 are deprecated but will remain supported. so that it's recommend to use Microsoft Power Apps
> and Power Automate as alternatives to Access Services 2010
> and 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Access Services 2010 and Access Services 2013 are available in SharePoint Server 2013 - 2019. I would recommend finding an alternative to using Access Services, though.

Comment: Yes, that what I have been reading "find an alternative". So what are the alternatives?

Comment: Often in these cases a SQL database + reporting solution (SSRS, Power BI, many others) + input solution (i.e. custom ASP.NET Core app) are often the best ways.

Not free, not part of SharePoint, and may require some development effort.

Comment: Sorry, as I indicated, getting a database is not an option. If I could I would.

Comment: In order to use Access Service(s), you'll have to have it create databases ;-). The only alternative is really to not use Access.